# Double row in pivot table from one post (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a listings form with categories and subcategories, and a pivot table to manage them. This is my Controller :

```
    $create = Listing::create(array(
    'title' => Input::get('title'),
    'description' => Input::get('description')
    ));

    $category = Input::get('category');

    $insert_id = $create->id;
    $listing = Listing::find($insert_id);

    $listing->categories()->attach($category);

    $listing->save();
```

When I post the listing, I would like to create another row in the pivot table with the same Listing_id but with different category (subcategory), and attach it:

```
    $subcategory = Input::get('subcategory');
```

*The system worked without pivot tables (with category_id and subcategory_id in the Listings table) and I use Nested sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things. Here is a revamped version of your code:

```
$listing = Listing::create(array(
    'title' => Input::get('title'),
    'description' => Input::get('description')
));

$listing->categories()->attach(Input::get('category'), array(
    'subcategory_id' => Input::get('subcategory'),
));
```

- The `$listing->save()` method is unnecessary as calling
  `Listing::create()` already calls the save method.
- The method `attach()` accepts a second array argument which allows you to enter in more information on the pivot table (such as your sub-category id)

I'd suggest looking at the eloquent documentation for more tips on related models.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models

From the laravel docs:

"You may also pass an array of attributes that should be stored on the pivot table for the relation:"

```
$user->roles()->attach(1, array('expires' => $expires));
```

In response to showing records that have a child category from looking into a parent category:

We can use a query scope to perform this for us (note, this is when using the package etrepat/baum).

This scope allows you to filter a model by a category, and see all records below the entered category as well.

Place this function inside your `Listing` model:

```
public function scopeCategory($query, $category_id = NULL){

        if($category_id){

            /*
             * Get descendants and self category nodes
             */
            $categories = $this->categories()->find($category_id)->getDescendantsAndSelf();

            /*
             * Perform a subquery on main query
             */
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($categories) {

                /*
                 * For each category, apply a orWhere query to the subquery
                 */
                foreach($categories as $category){
                    $query->orWhere('category_id', $category->id);
                }

                return $query;

            });

        }
}
```

How to use it (using category ID of 1 for example, you'd typically grab this from a user using Input::get()):

```
$listings = Listings::category(1)->all();
```

This will return all listings **that have a category_id of 1, as well as categories nested inside this category.**

Comment: If you're going to mass assign those inputs, then you might just as well get them from the form as an array. [ <input type="text" name="listing[title]" ... ] [ $listing = Listing::create(Input::get('listing'); ]

Comment: That would make it shorter yes, but that would be deliberately passing in all input from the user directly into the model, rather than defining exactly what fields are being set and from what input. The user could just edit the HTML of the web page on the fly and start trying to mass assign all fields on the model. Definitely don't like the sound of that.

Comment: Thank you, but when I do it in that way:   $listing->categories()->attach(Input::get('category'), array(
  'category_id' => Input::get('subcategory'),
  ));
In my database I get ID OK, CategoryID OK, but the ListingID is the subcategory ID, instead of creating another row with the subcategory and the same Listing ID

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand. If you're trying to re-create a nested set pattern, I'd suggest using this package: https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Comment: I'm using it but I thought it was appart from the thing I want to do. Every time you post the form, i want it to save as many entries as categories you selected, in this case two, in the pivot table (but with the same ListingID), so when you want to display parents and children they show the listings in both

Comment: Ohh I think I understand. You're trying to assign multiple categories for one listing? Is that correct? Or are you just trying to show listings in a child category when showing the higher parent category?

Comment: Yes, because if I assign one listing to categories (parents and children), I guess it's a way to show the listings in both, parent and children? At first that was what I thought, is there a better way to show listings in a child category when showing the higher parent category? Thanks

Comment: Yup, I already do this with a query scope, check out my edit. You don't want to have to duplicate records to get a listing to show up in a parent category, you should perform a query scope to look for all category_id's below the parent so listings with a category_id that are below the parent show up in your results.